# What s the difference between extensional and ostensive definition?

Tags: logic, definitions

As I understand

```
extensional definitions
```

are a subcategory of

```
ostensive definitions
```

. Both of them work with the extension of a term, with examples of the object, by pointing out which objects fall under the category of the defined term. But what is the difference between the two of them? And what would be some examples of such definitions?

Comment: Ostensive means that I point with my finger to a dog and I say "dog".

Comment: Extensional means that a concept is defined through the list of objects to which that concept apply to and not through aa list of properyies.

Comment: Wittgenstein famously rejects the idea that ostensive definitions can provide us with the meaning of a word per his [private language argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Investigations): *For Wittgenstein, the thing that the word stands for does not give the meaning of the word... So, for instance, there is no difference between pointing to a piece of paper, to its colour, or to its shape; but understanding the difference is crucial to using the paper in an ostensive definition of a shape or of a colour.*

Comment: When we say that "empty set" denotes a set without elements we are giving an extensional definition without pointing at anything. So extensional definitions are *not* a subcategory of ostensive definitions.

Comment: See [Ostensive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostensive_definition).

Comment: And see [Extensional and intensional definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensional_and_intensional_definitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that ostensive and extensional definitions both work by pointing out objects fall under the category of the term.

However, definition by extension works by listing all the objects in the class, like a list of all the members of a club. On the other hand, ostensive definition may or may not point out several objects that fall under the category of the term, though it does need to point out at least one. But these are examples, or better samples, and it is necessary for the learner to grasp how to apply the new term to new cases.

Wittgenstein points out that it is necessary to understand what kind of term is being defined. The learner does need to understand that "red" is a colour term in order to understand an ostensive definition of it. However, misunderstandings could, in principle, be dealt with by pointing out more samples of the term.

I hope that helps.